# Adding User Info to Permalink of User pages - is it neccessary?

Tags: permalinks

I have a page on my website that is currently accessible through http://domain.com/my-account/. This page also has some children pages that follow the same permalink structure

Is there any importance in adding additional user information to the permalink for security reasons? I was thinking about something like http://domain.com/my-account/user-ID.

It seems like it wouldn't really make any difference but I was wondering if it is recommended to do this. If so, is there a Wordpress function that makes this easy to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If such page is available only for users that are logged in (and I guess that's the point of having "my-account" page), then there is no reason to add anything more to that link. User has to be logged in to access such page and he will be redirected to that page after logging in.

On the other hand it is very important, that you use [nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) on any actions, that are performed in these pages - this will protect your users from XSS attacks. And of course, every action performed in there should also check, if user can perform that action (let's say user wants to delete his order/article - you have to check if current user is permitted to do anything with given article, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I was originally thinking about doing this is to prevent these pages from showing up in the search. I don't want users who are not logged in to see a "Edit Profile" page in their search results. Maybe I should look for a different way of doing this though.

Comment: So it's even more important, that you have only one my-account page and set it not to be indexed by search engines.